# iOS: plurals and custom locale

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, localization, nslocale

I'm developing app that supports "en" and "ru" languages, users can select language inside app.

If default phone's locale set to "en", but inside app selected "ru" language, then when trying to localize plural sentence ignored 'many'/'few' form. So it's localized by the English plural rules.

Definition:

```
<key>%d files</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@files@</string>
        <key>files</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>один файл</string>
            <key>many</key>
            <string>%d файлов</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%d файла</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Code to localize (manually create 'ru' locale):

```
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ru_RU")
String(format: NSLocalizedString("%d files", comment: ""),
                    locale: locale,
                    count)
```

As output i got:
for count = 1: "один файл" - and it's right
for count = 2: "2 файла" - it's also right (from category 'other')
for count = 6: "6 файла" - wrong, also from category 'other', but should be taken from 'many'

If i switch phone's language to Russian, then all being localized correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use keys:

**one** for 1 = один файл

**few** for 2-4 = 2 файла

**other** for all other cases

Comment: I know how it should be filled :) And it works properly in default  circumstances, but it has issues when used custom locale that doesn't match system language (e.g. if system language = 'en', but i use locale 'ru', which has different rules, then i will get wrong result)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite old question, but I've faced the same problem and this is how I fixed this:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ru", ofType: "lproj")!
let bundle = Bundle(path: path)!
let localizedString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("%d files", bundle: bundle, comment: ""),
                                     locale: NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ru_RU"),
                                     count)
```

The main idea is to make `NSLocalizedString` to search in language-specific bundle.